# Upload file and folder structure to S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The users in my site need to be able to upload a bunch of files and folders into S3 while maintaining the folder structure.

Say they have the following files in their local boxes.

```
/file1.jpg
/some_folder/file2.jpg
```

After upload, I need their s3 urls to be

```
http://s3bucket.amazon.com/usersfolder/file1.jpg
http://s3bucket.amazon.com/usersfolder/some_folder/file2.jpg
```

How can i do this ? To make matters a little more complicated, Upload from client side can be initiated only after they download an upload policy.

Edit: I would like to know a solution for the front end part of this question. Looks like on server i can use a wildcard character to specify access permissions, so i am good on that part.

I am using Node.JS/Express JS as a backend

Comment: You can use wildcards in signature. For example, you can grant rights to do anything under *http://s3bucket.amazon.com/usersfolder/* by adding  '*' in the end. Your users will then need to PUT to http://s3bucket.amazon.com/usersfolder/some_folder/file2.jpg this URL using the signature which can be done in browser. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, I think got that part covered,now I need to know how can i allow a folder upload on the client side...

Comment: folders do not exist in S3.  Think of S3 file structure as just really long filenames.  You are just allowing them to PUT to "s3bucket.amazon.com/usersfolder/*"   They cannot PUT a folder.  But they can PUT a bunch of files (that happen to be in a folder) s3bucket.amazon.com/usersfolder/file1.jpg s3bucket.amazon.com/usersfolder/file2.jpg

Comment: How are your users uploading the files? Are they using some client software, or uploading direct from the browser? What credentials are they using for their upload? If you are creating temporary Security Token Service credentials, you can always include a policy that ensures they are uploading to a specific directory, similar to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PolicyVariables.html

Comment: Uploading is done by an AngularJS directive from browser using a security policy. Uploading is not a problem, i want to know how to provide a user interface which allows the user to easily replicate their folder structure in s3.